# How do I assign the value from a text input to a variable in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently working on a basic signup / login ui in python using kivy. I want to capture the value typed into a TextInput widget and store that in a variable for later use. How would I go about doing this?

My text input widget in kv; this one in particular is prompting for a username.

```
TextInput:
    password: True
    multiline: False
    size_hint: 0.7, .05
    pos_hint: {"right": 0.9, 'top': 0.6}
```

I want to take the value in this and assign it to a variable.

The interface for the username and password prompts.

[image]

Comment: you say: *I want to take the value in this and assign it to variable.*, my question is when and where ?, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

From the [TextInput documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html):

`To create a singleline TextInput, set the TextInput.multiline property to False (the ‘enter’ key will defocus the TextInput and emit an TextInput.on_text_validate() event):`

```
def on_enter(instance, value):
    print('User pressed enter in', instance)

textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)
textinput.bind(on_text_validate=on_enter)
```

The `value` passed into `on_enter` is the text in the `TextInput`. You can assign it to a variable in the `on_enter` method.